# error page did not display in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying to learn servlet's error handling my aim was to redirect to error page whenever error code is 404 or 500. for this have written error.java and created error.jsp page  but its not gowing error page. please help me out why this is happening?FYI I am throwing error intentionally

my web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.Error</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Error</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/Error</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/Error</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Error.java

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Error
 */
public class Error extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Error() {
        super();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();

    Throwable throwable=(Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
    Integer code=(Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.statud_code");
     String servletName = (String)
              request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
              if (servletName == null){
                 servletName = "Unknown";
              }
              String requestUri = (String)
              request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
              if(requestUri==null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(requestUri)){
                  requestUri="unkniwn";
              }
              session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "error");
              session.setAttribute("errorCode", code);
              PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
              pw.println("error here");
              System.out.println("error:"+code);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Login.java

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        pw.println("Welcome "+user);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form method="post" action="first">
    Name:<input type="text" name="user" /><br/>
    Password:<input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi this error</h1>
<form method="post">
<div style="color: #FF0000;"> ${errorMessage} ${errorCode}</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 1:
I checked edge browser it is printing what I have written in print writer in Error.java but it is not redirecting me to /error url nor showing error.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `PrintWriter`, which is incorrect, rather you need to use `RequestDispatcher` to forward the request to the JSP page like below:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/Error.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

You can look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83726/basics4.htm) on servlet to JSP communication:

Comment: That works but when I run in debug mode it is showing servlet name is default servlet and error code is null. ideally it should be 404 and login servlet right?

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml in error page tag you try to put location for your own servlet. Instead of this you should use direct link to your own .jsp error page. You will be able to get exception from there via jstl

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/serverError.jsp</location> // Location to your jsp
</error-page>
```

And this is how to get exception message on page:
    `<c:set var="message" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}"/>`